# Data migration from postgres to hadoop

Tags: postgresql, hbase, sqoop, oltp

1) Shall I able to  import complete database by using Sqoop? If yes, what do you recommend in either  Hive or Hbase?

2) Will I be able to make this import process automated without human intervention?

3) How to replace postgres with habse completely.. i.e oltp

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Which problems do you have that you think Hadoop will solve?

Comment: Our management has decided to move data from postgresql to hadoop for better knowing about the complex data through hadoop